# My value in UITableview is repeated after 11th row in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I an getting same value in my tableview after the 11 row. 
after the 11th row again the name of row start as first row.

Comment: Assuming you have a question to ask, perhaps you might post some code that you're using to populate cells in your table view.

Comment: Is this also you? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838705/value-in-the-table-view-is-repeating-after-the-11th-row

Comment: Looks like this question was asked again by the same user (this time with code and thus it has a better answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839607/getting-the-same-name-for-the-table-rows-after-the-11th-row-of-the-uitableview

Let's close this one.  I suggest the author delete this question to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

How unfortunate.  Perhaps if you told us something about how you're populating the tableview, someone might be able to help you.

http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

In your table view data source you are probably calling dequeue to get a recycled UITableViewCell instance. If it returns nil, you are creating a new cell and putting the right data in it. If it returns a recycled cell, you are probably not updating it.

Move your updating code so that it is executed whether the cell is recycled or new.