# value in the Table view is repeating after the 11th row

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am beginner iphone developer I want created table in programatically. In the table we take more than 20 row. But i have some problem that after 11th row the same value repeated.

plz help me with code and other method

Comment: post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code here and someone will be able to point your mistake

Comment: Hi sounds like 11 rows is what will fit on the screen and you are no redrawing your cells correctly. As Vladimir writes: post the code. The error is probably in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [this question which is the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839607/getting-the-same-name-for-the-table-rows-after-the-11th-row-of-the-uitableview). In that case, the person was setting the text of the cell only when creating a new cell (when `nil` was returned from `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]`.) It needs to be set every time the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

Answer (score 0):

when you use reuseIdentifyer, the new cell to display is the cell that has just disappeared. so it will contain all the data from the disappeared cell. for example, if the cell, that has just disappeared, has detailDisclosureIndicator, the new cell will have it too even you don't set it.